# Decompile proguarded apk file

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, apk, decompiling

I have an apk that I release it myself. I have lost my main program I want to decompile the apk. My problem is that I had proguarded my app, so that after decompiling, my code is not properly shown. What should I do to have code of my program?!

Comment: You have tagged your question with "Kotlin". Was the lost source Kotlin or Java. because I don't know of any decompiler that would output Kotlin, only Java. Proguard only does some simple class and method renaming. If it is really code you have written you should recognize a lot classes by looking at them. Create a new Android Studio project and copy the code step-by-step into that project and rewrite the missing (not decompilable) parts. And the next time make backups of your source code...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my code is encrypted. My code was in Kotlin and for decompiling I just found decompile to Java. My main problem is proguard that I had in my app.

Comment: Proguard only removed unused parts and renames classes and methods. In most cases even the package structure remains intact (unless you explicitly configured to pack all classes into one package). That is just a simple obfuscation and as it is your code you should be able to "break" it.