# How to distinguish whether a specific class is app code or library code from the source code of decompiled APK?

Tags: android, apk, decompiling

I want to know if a specific class of decompiled APK source code belongs to the app code or library code.
It is judged by looking at the package name to which the class belongs, but some APKs are obfuscation from ProGuard, making it difficult to judge.
Is there an easy way to tell?
Is there any information in the AndroidManifest.xml that can distinguish the above information?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59908988/decompile-proguarded-apk-file

Comment: @MMG Not a solution for my question. Do you means it's impossible?

Comment: I think we can recognize which is library and which is code with help of names and other things but if the code is proguarded we can't know what was the code.

Comment: If package and class names have been completely obfuscated, then it is very difficult. It's not impossible, but would take a good knowledge of Proguard, finding a lot of good heuristic to match proguarded code with existing libraries, and a lot of work.